# issue in displaying a div

Tags: php, html, css

I have included a php page(courses.php) into another php page (course.php).
After including courses.php in course.php I have written a div tag and want it to be displayed next to the div having COURSES as header.

//Courses.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #top
            {
                height: 100px;
                border :0.5px solid;
            }
            #left
            {
                height: 520px;
                width: 250px;
                border :0.5px solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "top"></div>
        <div id = "left">
            <center>
                <h2><b> COURSES </h2></b>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "Html.html" target = "output"> HTML </a> 
               </li>
                    <li><a href = "C++.html" target = "output"> C++ </a> 
                </li>
                </ul>
            </center>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

[Page for Courses.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMS1j.jpg)

//course.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #center
            {

                height: 530px;
                width: 900px;
                border :0.5px solid;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

            <?php include("courses.php");?>

            <div id = "center">
            <h2>HEY</h2>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[page for Course.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNQdU.jpg)

I want the div showing HEY being displayed next to div showing COURSES.
Also advise how can I divide the div tag having HEY into two equal halves vertically.

Things which i tried for showing two divs next to each other:

1. including the include php tag in a div.
2. including the include php tag (in a div) as well as the next div tag both in 
   a parent div tag.
3. and then manipulating the float as well position property with different 
   combinations but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: You must have only one head and body, to get this work, you will have to merge files. Including is not a good idea

Comment: Please advise how is this merging done.

Comment: The `<center>` tag [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write like this in Courses.php

```
<style>
    #top
    {
        height: 100px;
        border :0.5px solid;
    }
    #left
    {
        height: 520px;
        width: 250px;
        border :0.5px solid;
    }
</style>

<div id = "top"></div>
<div id = "left">
    <center>
        <h2><b> COURSES </h2></b>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "Html.html" target = "output"> HTML </a> 
       </li>
            <li><a href = "C++.html" target = "output"> C++ </a> 
        </li>
        </ul>
    </center>
</div>
```

body element is allowed to include style but this is not a good practice, you are encourage to split to two files, Courses.php and Courses_css.php and import them right place in Course.php

Comment: Thank you,
I have included inline css for courses.php and internal css in course.php,
but again while trying to get the div having HEY next to the div having COURSES I tried both float and position property but nothing was helpful in the getting the two div adjacent.
Any help on this would be appreciated.